# Границы применения в django-проекте rest-framework'a?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, rest

Внедряю в проект rest-framework и нужны советы для его большего понимания.

Понятно, что rest-framework необходим для построения API и работы с внешними потребителями (разработчиками, прочими сервисами). Но интересует можно ли использовать данные, которые отдает фреймворк, для внутренних взаимодействий.

К примеру, до внедрения rest, детализация объекта доступна по ссылке:

```
 element/<element_id>
```

которой соответствует вью:

```
class ElementDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Element
    template = "element-detail.html"
    ....
    <какие-то переопределенные методы родителя>
```

после внедрения rest данные объекта также доступны по ссылке

```
api/v1/element/<element_id>
```

и собственно вопрос, **могут ли части моего проекта обмениваться данными с использованием rest-framework?**

К примеру, если я хочу реализовать ajax-подгрузку данных объекта, я где-нибудь во вью допишу следующий код:

```
class ElementDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Element
    template = "element-detail.html"
    ....
    <какие-то переопределенные методы родителя>
    ....
    if request.is_ajax():
        return json-object
```

соответственно, в скрипте url будет ссылаться на эту вью, а полученные данные обрабатываться уже средствами скрипта.

но в случае rest-framework могу ли я в скрипте использовать url от rest-api?

```
api/v1/element/<element_id>
```

будет ли это правильно? или для внутренних взамодействий использовать только внутренние классы и функции, а rest только для внешних взаимодействий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> К примеру, если я хочу реализовать ajax-подгрузку данных объекта, я где-нибудь во вью допишу следующий код ...
>
> ... но в случае rest-framework могу ли я в скрипте использовать url от rest-api?

Именно так стараюсь и делать в последнее время, избавляясь от конструкций вида:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    return json-object
```

Которые с разрастанием и усложнением проекта становится трудно поддерживать.

Я в своих проектах чаще DRF использую именно для внутрених нужд, нет в этом ничего плохого.

Comment: спасибо, то есть, как понимаю, мы может использовать drf везде, где отдаваемые данные соответсвуют ожиданиям? фактически мы можем заменить DetailView на результат детализации drf, только кастомизировать шаблон (при условии, что ничего кроме детализации на странице не будет)?

Comment: насчёт отдачи html точно не знаю, я DRF так не использовал. Я имел ввиду случай когда нужно получить данные в виде json, например когда их запрашивает какой то виджет на странице. Тоесть обычная вьюха отдаёт HTML страницу а если на этой странице нужны какие то данные в виде json тогда берём их из DRF.

Comment: вот к примеру если вам понадобится отдавать json объект с усечённым составом полей (для разных виджетов). Городить эту логику в коде основной вьюхи неудобно.

Comment: то есть на каждый объект определенного типа будем писать свой сериалайзер?

Comment: да, часто бывает что на один объект в разных ситуациях пишется несколько наборов сериализаторов. Например получить заказ с вложеным пользователем, или заказ только с его id.

Comment: если будет время можете дать совет по этому вопросу? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584113/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5