# Сериализатор с большим количеством одинаковых зависимых моделей

Tags: python, django, rest, serialize, django-rest-framework

Пишу сериализатор на Джанго для модели с большой вложенностью и большим количеством зависимых моделей (OneToOne).

Основная модель:

```python
class Element(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Element'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Elements'

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    symbol = models.CharField(verbose_name="Symbol", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    atomic_number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Atomic Number", blank=True, null=True)
    atomic_weight = models.CharField(verbose_name="Atomic Weight", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

Одна из зависимых:

```python
class Group(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Group'

    element = OneToOneField(Element)
    type = models.CharField(verbose_name='Type', max_length=50, choices=TYPE)
    value = models.CharField(verbose_name="Value", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(verbose_name="Unit", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

Соответственно в сериализаторе, мне необходимо отобразить эту вложенность. Если бы зависимая модель была одна, выглядело бы так:

```python
class ElementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_data')

    def get_data(self, obj):
        data = {}
        data['type'] = obj.group.type
        data['value'] = obj.group.value
        data['unit'] = obj.group.unit

        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Element
        fields = '__all__'
```

И давало подобный результат:

```python
    {
        "id": 2,
        "group": {
            "type": "classification",
            "unit": null,
            "value": "18"
        },
        "name": "Helium",
        "symbol": "He",
        "atomic_number": 2,
        "atomic_weight": "4.002602"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "group": {
            "type": "classification",
            "unit": null,
            "value": "1"
        },
        "name": "Hydrogen",
        "symbol": "H",
        "atomic_number": 1,
        "atomic_weight": "1.00794"
    },
```

**И к вопросу**

Как видно, сериализатор представляет из себя частный случай. В действительности свойств, подобных Group, больше сотни и описывать каждое своим методом не хорошо.

Как понимаю, должен быть абстрактый метод, который принимает название поля и работает с ним. Поля, так и быть, сформирую автоматически заранее и копипастой вставлю в этот файл, но без абстрактного метода будет все очень громоздко:

```python
class ElementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    <title> = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_data')
    <title> = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_data')
    <title> = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_data')
    .....

    def get_data(self, obj):
        data = {}
        data['type'] = obj.<title>.type
        data['value'] = obj.<title>.value
        data['unit'] = obj.<title>.unit

        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Element
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Могу я вытащить название поля и использовать его во внутреннем методе?** Или свернул совсем не туда и для таких сложных детлизаций объекта все решается иначе?

Comment: Поправил название вопроса для лучшего представления сути